# Finding a word which is not a substring of another word

Tags: java

how can one find a word of length say x 
which is not a substring of another word of length y ,
where

x
<
y?
e.g

```
word is - apple
req word - ape
word is aaabbab
req word - aba
```

Comment: What would make "ape" the answer in the first question as opposed to, say, "can"?

Comment: @paranay It seems to me like you want to check "are the chars of x in y"? Otherwise I don't get it. :)

Comment: it is not a substring of "apple"

Comment: @InsertNickHere : yes i meant the char sequence

Comment: my answer gives you a way of ensuring one word is not a substring of the other, but I'm not sure how you're trying to form word x. Does it have to be made of characters that exist in y?

Comment: @Rob Cooney: no it can be any word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this is what's asked:

```
public class SubsequenceNotSubtring {
    static void subseqNotSubstring(String word, int L) {
        search(word, L, "", 0);
    }
    static void search(String word, int L, String subseq, int index) {
        if (L == 0 && !word.contains(subseq)) {
            System.out.println(subseq);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < word.length(); i++) {
            search(word, L-1, subseq + word.charAt(i), i+1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subseqNotSubstring("apple", 3);
        subseqNotSubstring("aaabbab", 3);
    }
}
```

This lists all [subsequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of a given length from a given string that are not [substrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring).

The above snippet finds the following (annotated, dupes removed):

```
apple,3   => apl, ape, ale, ppe
aaabbab,3 => aba, bbb
```

It should be noted that this algorithm is naive brute force and has horrible asymptotic complexity. Better algorithms with more sophisticated string data structure could certainly be concocted if necessary. The most promising direction would be to use a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Comment: Please clarify if this is what's desired, and if this is a homework/research problem/programming contest, etc.

Comment: it was a part of programme i was trying to think of

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check for x.length() < y.length() and y.indexOf(x)==-1

Answer (score 1):

Like this for instance:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNotSubstring {

    public String notSubstring(String sY, int x) {
        if (sY.length() > x) {
            String sX = sY.substring(0, x - 1);
            sX = sX + (new Character((char) (sY.charAt(x)+1)).toString());
            return sX;
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                sb.append("a");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testApple() {
        String sY = "apple";
        String sX = notSubstring(sY, 3);
        System.out.println(sX);
        assert(!sY.contains(sX));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrange() {
        String sY = "orange";
        String sX = notSubstring(sY, 5);
        System.out.println(sX);
        assert(!sY.contains(sX));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about starting by doing the (probably slow) but very simple to understand

```
 Generate a list of letter combinations

     a p p
     a p p l
     a p p l e
     a p l
     a p l e
     a p e
     a l e  <=== look another answer
     p p l
     p p l e
     p l e

 Test each list item to see a). whether it is a substring b) whether it is a word
```

Generating that list would work nicely as a recursive routine.

Comment: How does the answer you accepted differ? Won't that be exactly as slow?